# Measure length in pixels over raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In MATLAB there is a simple tool called [imdistline](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdistline.html) which measures length in **pixels** over an image.

I can't find an equivalent tool in QGIS (3.26.3) for measuring the length between two pixels on a raster interactively where the `Measure Line tool` can't measure in pixels for a georeferenced raster (like geotiff ) and simply measures in meters, degrees, etc.

Comment: Divide length by pixel size?

Comment: @user30184 Am looking for a more direct method

Comment: As a workaround you could remove the georeferencing from the image. The default georererenced pixel size is then 1 by 1. But you probably want to have the georeferencing for other purpose so I fear I can't say what to do.

Comment: How are you expecting to interact with the image? It sounds like you are expecting to click two points on the raster and have the tool return the length of the hypotenuse in pixels?

Comment: @TomBrennan yes, like the distance tool in qgis works, just instead of meters in pixels.